# Pushnavigation is not working with custom alert in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uialertview

I am using my custom alert to log out of the application

in custom alert, I have tried to log out with firebase after the successful logout using navigation push controller to sign in the controller but it will not redirect to sign in screen

Here is my custom alert code

```
let customAlert = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomAlertID") as! AlertViewController
        customAlert.titleLbl = "Log out"
        customAlert.imageTitle = "logout"
        customAlert.descryptionText = "You will be returned to the login screen. Are you sure you want to logout?"
        customAlert.okBtnText = "LOG OUT"

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            customAlert.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
            customAlert.definesPresentationContext = true
            customAlert.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
            customAlert.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve
            self.present(customAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

Here is my logout click button code

```
 let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
          do {
            try firebaseAuth.signOut()
              let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInViewController") as! SignInViewController
              self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)

              DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                  self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
              }

              let domain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
              UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: domain)
              UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
              print(Array(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().keys).count)
          } catch let signOutError as NSError {
              self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            print("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
          }
        }
```

without the alert view, it will works

Comment: Why do you push a vc and then pop to root ?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the navigationController property to not be equal to `nil`, you must add your custom alertViewController to the navigation stack using `pushViewController` method. In your case, you are only presenting a custom alertViewController that does not know anything about your `navigationController`

There is another way to implement:

After initializing a custom view controller, you should pass it the necessary closure functions that should work after pressing the button

Example:

```swift
let customAlert = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomAlertID") as! AlertViewController
        customAlert.titleLbl = "Log out"
        customAlert.imageTitle = "logout"
        customAlert.onClickExit = { [weak self] in
            self?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
...
```

Comment: My alert view controller is already in the navigation stack. then why push is not working?

Answer (score 0):

After Logout, you should set Another Root view controller and Your navigationController Stack Must be Clear.

```
let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInViewController") as! SignInViewController
let signInNavController = UINavigaionController(rootViewController: controller)
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = signInNavController
```